# How can I create bubble grid charts in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I want to create bubble grid charts with ggplot.
somthing like this:
[image]

I couldnt find any code or exampe online.

Thanks

Comment: one produces this with excel ... there is no example with ggplot2. However coding oneself this might not be that difficult ...

Answer (score 3):

Using `geom_point` with discrete x and y scales will get you started. Here's an example with some quick toy data:

```
library(tidyverse)

offenses <- c("robbery", "violence", "drugs")
actions <- c("formal", "informal", "considered")
counts <- sample(10:100, 9, replace = TRUE)

data <- expand.grid(offenses = offenses, actions = actions) %>% bind_cols(counts = counts)

ggplot(data,
       aes(x = str_to_title(offenses), 
           y = str_to_title(actions),
           colour = str_to_title(offenses),
           size = counts)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(aes(label = counts), 
            colour = "white", 
            size = 3) +
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top") +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(10, 30)) + # Adjust as required.
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set2") +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

[image: bubbles]

Play around with the `range` parameter of `scale_size_continouous` as needed to get bubbles of a reasonable size for your data set.

Comment: I would recommend `labs(x = NULL, y = NULL)` to completely eliminate the labels rather than drawing empty strings (which take up vertical space).

Comment: Good point! Thank you. Never realised you could do that. I've updated code and image for those who don't make it to the comments.

Comment: @MSR,  thanks for the solution! can you please advise: what's the way to change the border size of the bubbles? (there are white rims around the bubbles when I run the code)

Comment: For the above example, you'll need to map `offenses` to `fill` instead of `colour` (i.e. `fill = str_to_title(offenses)` in the `aes` block), and then change `geom_point()` to `geom_point(shape = 21, stroke = 3)` - replace the `3` with whatever stroke parameter you desire. Hope that helps.

Comment: Also, with thouse changes, you can now use `colour` in `geom_point()` to control the border colour to change from the default black. Of course, you can also map it to your data by setting colour in the `aes` of the plot or `geom_point`, should you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I also tried meanwhile. It looks very similar ...

```
require(ggplot2)
require(ggsci) # for the scale_fill_npg()

grid.bubble.plot <- function(df, 
                             axis_labels_size=16, 
                             aspect_ratio=1/1,
                             values_text_size=3,
                             values_text_color="white",
                             x_axis_position="top", # or "bottom",
                             bubble_size_range=c(5, 24),
                             bubble_alpha=0.5,
                             bubble_shape=21,
                             bubble_edge_stroke=0) {
    col_names <- colnames(df)
    row_names <- rownames(df)
    values <- as.vector(as.matrix(df))
    values_x <- as.vector(sapply(col_names, function(i) rep(i, nrow(df))))
    values_y <- as.vector(rep(row_names, dim(df)[2]))
    res_df <- data.frame(values = values, values_x = values_x, values_y)
    gg <- ggplot(res_df, aes(x=values_x, y=values_y, size = values, fill=factor(values_x))) +
                 geom_point(alpha=bubble_alpha, shape=bubble_shape, stroke=bubble_edge_stroke) +
                 scale_size(range = bubble_size_range) +
                 scale_fill_npg() +
                 scale_x_discrete(position = x_axis_position) +
                 geom_text(aes(label=values), size=values_text_size, color=values_text_color) +
                 theme(line=element_blank(), 
                       panel.background=element_blank(),
                       legend.position="none",
                       axis.title=element_blank(),
                       axis.text=element_text(size=axis_labels_size),
                       aspect.ratio=aspect_ratio)
    gg
}

grid.bubble.plot(df)
```

Play around with the values.

e.g. you can make also the text size vary with the values:

```
# thanks to @MSR for example dataset
require(tidyverse)
offenses <- c("robbery", "violence", "drugs")
actions <- c("formal", "informal", "considered")
counts <- sample(10:100, 9, replace = TRUE)
df <- expand.grid(offenses = offenses, actions = actions) %>% bind_cols(counts = counts)


grid.bubble.plot(df, values_text_size=as.vector(as.matrix(df)))
```

For color, you can try other `scale_fill_` variants like:
 `_aaas()` `_lancet()` `_jco()` `_tron()`

Comment: thanks for the post. when I run it, it shows "Error in as.vector(x, mode) :   cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'any'". Can you please have a look?

Comment: @MarkK that error occurs always if you use `df` but didn't defined the dataframe as `df`` before. - `df` is in base package a function thus a closure.